# How to write a .feature file that tests deletion by an ID that I can't control?

Tags: bdd, automated-tests, jbehave, gherkin, uid

There is an API call like:

```
public int deleteGroup(String groupIdentifier) throws Exception;
```

I wrote a .feature:

```
Scenario: Deleting an existing group (by its ID) successfully
    Given I am authorized
    And <groupid> is already stored in WAAD
    When I call the delete group method for group <groupid>
    Then group <groupid> should NOT be present in WAAD

Examples:
    |    groupid    |
    |  test.group1  |
    |  test.group2  |
```

How can I ensure that the given UID is in the database if I cannot create an entry by UID? I can create a group by name.

Comment: What is the goal of this test? What do we want to verify? That the group can be deleted? Or that it can be deleted specifically by group ID?

Comment: The goal is to verify that the any group can be deleted by its group ID.

Answer (score 1):

Write your scenario like this:

```
Scenario: Deleting an existing group (by its ID) successfully
    Given I am authorized
    And a group named "whatever" is already stored in WAAD
    When I call the delete group method for the group named "whatever"
    Then the group named "whatever" should NOT be present in WAAD
```

- In step 2, create the group.
- In step 3, look up the group by name, determine its ID, and delete it by that ID.
- In step 4, look up the group by name and assert that it isn't there.

This is a normal pattern that I've used many times. It requires some extra queries, but it relieves you of having to know IDs.

Comment: Sorry for not being concrete enough but the Scenario is given this way. `Deleting an existing group by its ID successfully` (I have modified my original question).

Comment: I clarified that the deletion in my example is by ID.

Answer (score 0):

one of my colleague provided quite a good solution. He suggested to have a scenario like this:

```
Scenario: Deleting an existing group (by its Id) successfully
    Given I am authorized
    And <groupname> is already stored in WAAD
    When I call the delete group method for group with <groupname> by its ID
    Then group <groupname> should NOT be present in WAAD
Examples:
|   geroupname  |
|  test.group1  |
|  test.group2  |
```

With this approach I emphasize that test implementation should use delete by ID but the test method's parameter is the name. So I can create at WHEN and store its ID.